# making a String from a loop(Arraylist) and several individual signs to mysql commandline

Tags: java, mysql, string, loops, arraylist

I might have overlooked some factors influencing the process but that is why i seek help here. It is my first post here and i have read the initial prescriptions for helping me getting the best question as a basis for the best answer. I hop you will understand(otherwise please make a comment with further questions)

The case is that i have been creating an `ArrayList`

```
ArrayList<String> liste = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I gather several names, quantities, and dates:

```
if(shepherd == 0) {
} else if(shepherd <= 0) {
    System.out.println(shepherd);               
    String s = "('shepherd'," +  "'" +  shepherd + "'," +"'" + ft.format(date) + "'" + ")";
    liste.add(s);
}
```

I have defined `shepherd` as follows:

```
double shepherd = 0;
```

Next, I wish to add these entries to my MySql database.

I construct a query, and print it out so that I can verify that it is of the correct format:

```
System.out.println("INSERT INTO kennel VALUES");

for(int i = 0; i < liste.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(liste.get(i));

    if(i != liste.size()-1) {
        System.out.println(",");
    }
}
```

This shows the correct command, with the proper syntax, but it's only output to the console at this point.

I have to send this through some Jsch or Ganymed. Most likely as a String. So i am wondering how i could take all the different parts, the doubles, the strings, the loop and build up a String, identical to the printed line i get in console.

I sensed it would look like this:

```
String command = (mysql -e "use kennel;insert into department3 values ('shepherd','1','2013-03-04');";
```

I believe that I am having some trouble with the `"` and `(` and `'`.

I hope i made it clear what the trouble is about. Thank you in advance. Sincerely

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Mikkel. You could use a `StringBuilder` instance to produce your target `String`. How do you plan on sending your string to MySql to execute?

Comment: consider using JDBC instead of executing `mysql -e` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your string need to be held within quotation marks. Because this will interfere with the quotation marks within your String, you need to escape them. You can do this by placing a backslash in front of the character. :)

```
String command = "(mysql -e \"use kennel;insert into department3 values ('shepherd','1','2013-03-04');\"";
```